# Converting Joomla value from database into PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.3

I want to take some information created in a Joomla article into a separate system separate from Joomla.  Here is an example value returned from a field I grabbed from a MySQL query (the column is "images" from the "com_content" table):

```
{"image_intro":"images\/Capitol_-_D_C__-_Daytime.jpg","float_intro":"right","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

Now in PHP I want to convert this sucker into an array.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_decode()` in PHP will be your friend, see the docs:
http://docs.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Something like this:

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to json decode the result

```
$image_intro = json_decode($image);
$image = $image_intro->image_intro;
```

To simply display the result once decoded, you can use

```
echo $image;
```

or maybe if you wanted to display the actual image, you could use this:

```
<img src="<?php echo JUri::root() . $image; ?>" />
```